# 3D Viewport Gizmo - Axes are missing, but zoom, pan buttons are visible

Tags: gizmo

Navigation Gizmo - 3d axes are missing - but not the zoom, pan buttons. Could you please tell me how to fix this?
[image: Navigation Gizmo - 3d axes are missing - but not the zoom, pan buttons]

Comment: Hmmm... strange, I never had that. Usually you can disable it in the _Viewport Gizmos_ menu with the _Navigate_ option - but this would turn off the other symbols there as well.

Comment: Yes, when I do that, the buttons turn on and off but I cant see the axes

Answer (score 3):

Go to the top menu *Edit* > *Preferences* > *Viewport*. There you will presumably find that the *3D Viewport Axis* is set to *Off*. Switch it to *Simple Axis* to get the default navigate gizmo back.

[image: navigate gizmo]

Comment: Awesome! It worked. Thanks a lot